# Trim trailing space from table contents

Tags: sql-server, trim, nvarchar

I have a table in a SQL server 2000 database with a nvarchar(30) field "details". There are some 10,000 records in that with a trailing space. I need a query to trim the particular field content in all rows. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET details = RTRIM(details)
```

For padding, you could do, for instance:

```
UPDATE table SET details = details + '    '
```

or

```
UPDATE table SET details = '    ' + details
```

Comment: Thanks. How to pad the entries purposely with some leading or trailing characters?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do this in a select statement only, use

```
SELECT RTRIM(Val)
FROM Table
```

If you wish to change the values in the table, use update

```
UPDATE Table
SET Val = RTRIM(Val)
```

For padding puposes you can use replicate

```
SELECT REPLICATE('*', 10) + 'TADA'
```